# Hide product price and disable add to cart for specific product categories in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price, taxonomy-terms

I'm looking for the right code that hides the prices for some specific categories in Woocommerce.

I already have the code to hide the prices on de single product page:

```
add_action( 'wp', 'remove_prices_based_on_category' );
function remove_prices_based_on_category() {
    // On product single pages 
    if ( is_product() ) {
        remove_product_price( get_the_ID() );
    }
}

function return_custom_price( $price, $instance ) {
    $price = '<span style="color:red; font-size:12px;">Call our office <strong>516.695.3110</strong> for prices.</span>';
    return $price; 
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'remove_product_price', 5, 1 ); // for each product on product listing page/shop page.
function remove_product_price( $product_id ) {
    $product_id  = get_the_ID();
    $hidden_price_category_ids = array( '27419','27421' ); // Add Product Category IDs for which the product price should be hidden.
    $product_cat_ids  = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' ); // Getting all categories for this product.
    $cat_ids = wp_list_pluck( $product_cat_ids, 'term_id' ); // Getting all category ids for this product.   
    $result = array_intersect( $hidden_price_category_ids, $cat_ids ); // Will match hidden price categories with product categories and the cat id in the array.

    // If a hidden price category is found
    if( !empty($result) ) {
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'return_custom_price', 10, 2 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
    } else {
        remove_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'return_custom_price', 10, 2 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
    }
}
```

How can I do it for WooCommerce archive pages?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/arsalan13nov/bb7a8ff2c508ef547312671bd4dff5db

Comment: As a new user, you could take [the quick tour (30 seconds)](https://stackoverflow.com//tour) that basically explains how StackOverFlow work.

Answer (score 3):

Your existing code is complicated, uncompleted and not really convenient. Try the following instead that will work for single product pages **and archives pages  too** *(as shop page)*.

It handles any kind of product, including variable products and their variations.

For defined product categories, it replace the price and disable add to cart button  on related products.

The code:

```
// Custom conditional function that check for specific product categories
function check_for_defined_product_categories( $product_id ) {
    // HERE your Product Categories where the product price need to be hidden.
    $targeted_terms = array( '27419','27421' ); // Can be term names, slugs or Ids

    return has_term( $targeted_terms, 'product_cat', $product_id );
}

// Custom function that replace the price by a text
function product_price_replacement(){
    return '<span style="color:red; font-size:12px;">' . sprintf( __( "Call our office %s for prices."), '<strong>516.695.3110</strong>' ) . '</span>';
}

// Replace price by a text (conditionally)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'filter_get_price_html_callback', 10, 2 );
function filter_get_price_html_callback( $price, $product ){
    if( check_for_defined_product_categories( $product->get_id() ) ) {
        $price = product_price_replacement();
    }
    return $price;

}

// Hide prices and availiability on product variations (conditionally)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'filter_available_variation_callback', 10, 3 ); // for Variations
function filter_available_variation_callback( $args, $product, $variation ) {
    if( check_for_defined_product_categories( $product->get_id() ) ) {
        $args['price_html'] = '';
        $args['availability_html'] = '';
    }
    return $args;
}

// Disable add to cart button (conditionally)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable', 'woocommerce_is_purchasable_filter_callback', 10, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'woocommerce_is_purchasable_filter_callback', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_is_purchasable_filter_callback( $purchasable, $product ) {
    $product_id = $product->get_parent_id() > 0 ? $product->get_parent_id() : $product->get_id();

    if( check_for_defined_product_categories( $product_id ) ) {
        $purchasable = false;
    }
    return $purchasable;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.